# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed (no mongoose)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I am trying to write  a simple case where I am hitting a route and checking the response.

My tests work but every time it also throws this msg:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Here is my unit test:

```
 // we will use supertest to test HTTP requests/responses
import request = require('supertest');
import bodyParser1 = require('body-parser');

// we also need our app for the correct routes!
const index = require('./index');
index.use(bodyParser1.json());
index.use(bodyParser1.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

describe('GET / ', () => {
  test('Test sample get', async done => {
    const response: any = await request(index).get('/');    
    expect(response.text).toEqual('Welcome to Minos');
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    done();
  });
});
afterAll(async done => {
  done();
});
```

and here is my index.ts:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.send('Welcome to Minos');
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Did you find any answer? because I am facing the same problem. Jest version is "24.8.0".

Comment: @jan nope, still waiting :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one? I hope this way can solve your problem.

```
describe('GET / ', () => {
  test('Test sample get', async () => {
    const response: any = await request(index).get('/');    
    expect(response.text).toEqual('Welcome to Minos');
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  }, 20000);
});
```

Also `done` is not necessary with async/await approach.